# Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: window.parent.globalFunction is not a function

Tags: javascript, typeerror

***test.js*** file code:

```
window.globalFunction = () => {
    console.log("Global Function");
}
```

***access.js*** file:

```
export default class myClass{
    functionCall = () => {      
        window.parent.globalFunction();

    }
}
```

Both are in same directory and i am getting this error.

Comment: Please tell more about where these scripts are going to call. Are they called in the same window?

Comment: they are in the same folder like

Comment: accessfolder -> test.js

Comment: accessfolder-> access.js

Comment: In access,js i have a class followed with the export keyword.                     export default class myClass{
    functionCall = () => {
           
        window.parent.globalFunction();
        
    }
}                                                                                                                                                And this class is import in the react file

Comment: no the html document is not using those scripts

Comment: they are called by importing the class in the react.jsx file. By creating the object of the class and then calling the function

Comment: the main issue is with the global scope for the window object. It should work in a way that i am doing write now but i don't know why it is causing scope issue.

Comment: Please update your question and add these details to the question

Comment: I there something wrong of what i am doing?

Comment: Not at all, I just want to help you to improve your question. At this moment, your question can cause others to misunderstand the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Window.parent is to allow code in an iframe to call code in the parent page.  If you are just importing a je module, you can just call `window.globalFunction()` from your module

Comment: Then you are doing something else wrong that you have not mentioned in your question